# Combine date and time to be a datetime not a string in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, date, datetime, time

Currently I have two tags -> date and time.

One is DateFrom and another one is for DateTo.

I need the DateFrom and DateTo times to be fixed. From to be 00:00:00.000Z and TO to be 23:59:59.999Z.

Obviously I want to skip that conversion. I want to use dates and send them as dates and not have a workaround with these strings.

```
<template>
<div id="bnbReport">
    <br>
    <form>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend reportInput">
            <span class="input-group-text">FromDate</span>
            <input type="date" v-model="fromDateDefault" :max="toDateDefault" />
            <input type="time" value='00:00:00' disabled=true />
        </div>
        <div class="input-group-prepend reportInput">
            <span class="input-group-text">ToDate</span>
            <input type="date" v-model="toDateDefault" :min="fromDateDefault" />
            <input type="time" value='23:59:59' disabled=true />
        </div>
        <b-button-group>
          <b-button variant="outline-info" @click="downloadZip">
            <b-icon-download />Download
          </b-button>
        </b-button-group>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import { createNamespacedHelpers } from 'vuex'
const { mapActions } = createNamespacedHelpers('reports')

const today = new Date()
const oneWeekAgo = new Date(today.getTime() - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
export default {
  name: 'BnbReport',
  data () {
    return {
      toDate: today.toISOString().substr(0, 10),
      fromDate: oneWeekAgo.toISOString().substr(0, 10)
    }
  },
  computed: {
    fromDateDefault: {
      get () {
        return this.fromDate
      },
      set (val) {
        this.fromDate = val
      }
    },
    toDateDefault: {
      get () {
        return this.toDate
      },
      set (val) {
        this.toDate = val
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(['reports', 'fetchBnbReport']),
    async downloadZip () {
      const fromDateTime = this.fromDate + 'T' + '00%3A00%3A00.000Z'
      const toDateTime = this.toDate + 'T' + '23%3A59%3A59.999Z'
      console.log(fromDateTime)
      const paramsToSend = { DateFrom: fromDateTime, DateTo: toDateTime }
      const res = await this.fetchBnbReport(paramsToSend)
      const fileURL = `data:application/zip;base64,${res}`
      const fileLink = document.createElement('a')
      fileLink.href = fileURL
      fileLink.setAttribute('download', 'bnbReport.zip')
      document.body.appendChild(fileLink)
      fileLink.click()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: What does `fetchBnBeport` use to send the dates? (axios? fetch?, etc.)

Comment: Hi tony19. Axios is used to fetch the dates.

Comment: Why do you escape the colons in the ISO date strings?